# Batch LEQ & GEQ Problems

Tags: windows, batch-file

So I am making a batch project, I'm asking the user what their age is, if I type a number under 16, it works just fine, however if I type a number greater than, or equal to 16, both outcomes of the statement happens, why is this, and how can I fix it?

```
echo What is your age
set /p age=
goto determine
:determine
if %age% GEQ 16 goto oldenough
if %age% LEQ 15 goto min
:oldenough
echo You are old enough... What will you now do.
:min
echo You are not old enough... Leave.
pause
```

Comment: See `Goto /?` and read last paragraph.

Comment: Execution just continues after `echo You are old enough...` unless you tell it not to do so...

Comment: Read `help call` and `help if`.  If 16 is the cutoff age, then 15 doesn't figure into the problem.

Comment: A `GOTO` is not a call to a function.  It just places the execution of the program to that label within the code and continues executing all the code from there.  Pretty much how the `GOTO` functions in every language that has used it since the dawn of the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Batch files just jump to the label you specified in the `goto`

It then continues executing from there.  It doesn't skip the next label.

Two solutions:

1. Add more conditions and more `goto` statements
2. put the subroutines in separate batch files and use `call` to run them

Comment: Yeah but it shouldnt execute the next goto because "age" is greater than 15

Comment: it only executes one goto but falls through from one label to the next

Comment: just add `if %age% GEQ 16 goto end` after `echo you are old enough` and add an end label at the end

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example layout to help you:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
Echo Core 0.0.1
Echo By Supergrupgr
Echo SpukkitDev 2020
"%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /T 5
Set "age=0"
Set /P "age=What is your age? >"
If %age% Lss 16 (
    Echo=
    Echo You are not old enough... Leave.
    Echo=
    "%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /T 3 /NoBreak 1> NUL
    Exit /B 1
)
Echo You are old enough... What will you now do?
"%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /T 3 1> NUL
```

I have included the last line, just to prevent the window from closing to quickly, *should the [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) not have been run from the Command Prompt*.

To find out more about each command, open up a Command Prompt window, then enter each of the following, *as necessary*: `Echo /?`, `"%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /?`, `Set /?`, `If /?`, and `Exit /?`.

*Notes*

1. You'll notice the `=` immediately following `Echo` on two of the lines. This is effectively a random character, included to prevent `Echo` from displaying it's current status, (`on` or `off`). The result is to output empty lines for visual appearance.
2. You'll need a minimum requirement of Windows Vista, to use the built-in `Timeout` utility.

Comment: @jwdonahue, the answer was initially provided to show a particular methodology, which I think it has. I did that because the suggestions at the time, were suggesting the use of `Call` and/or `GoTo`, both of which add an unnecessary overhead. It's a community wiki, feel free to make improvements/additions, or to simply look at the syntax used in formatting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First we write the algorithm:

```
Get user's age.
If age 16 or older, go do big kid stuff and exit,
else go do little kid stuff and exit.
```

Writing that in code looks something like:

```batch-file
@setlocal EnableExtensions

@call :SetAge
@if %_age% GEQ 16 (@call :BigKidStuff) else (@call :LittleKidStuff)
@exit /b

:BigKidStuff
@echo You are old enough... What will you do now?
@exit /b 0

:InstructUser
@echo How old are you?  Please enter a number between 0 and 199.
@exit /b 0

:LittleKidStuff
@echo You are not old enough... Leave.
@exit /b 1

:SetAge
:_tryAgain
@call :InstructUser
@set /p _age=
@rem Check for numeric input and age limitations:
@set _inputVerified=0
@for /L %%N in (0,1,199) do @(@if "%%N" EQU "%_age%" @set _inputVerified=1)
@if not %_inputVerified% EQU 1 (@goto :_tryAgain)
@rem If we get this far, we have valid input between in the 0..199 range.
@exit /b 0
```

NOTE: I did not do a lot of testing on this, but I think covered all the code paths at least once. Give it a try.

See `help setlocal`, `help for`, `help call`, `help goto`, `help if` and `help exit`, to learn more about the above code.

Stylistic notes:

- I use the `@` symbols throughout, rather than an `@echo off` because it is more composable with other scripts and makes targeted debugging easier.
- I use a different style of label names for `goto` targets than `call` targets.
- I avoid using multi-line code blocks (more than one line between paren's) like the plague.